# Fire event when Angular navigates to a new page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-router

I am hacking on an Angular application.  I'm not *developing* in Angular, mind you, but customizing the rendered user interface using JavaScript.  I do not have access to the Angular source or build system.  (It's stupid... don't ask.)

I'm listening for appearance of a particular element to appear in the DOM, on `http://example.com/page_2`.  Once it appears, I wish to add another element.  It works fine if you directly access `http://example.com/page_2` in your browser, but not if you visit `http://example.com/page_1` and then *navigate* to `/page_2`.  So I want to catch the route change.

Watching the URL via `window.location.href` doesn't seem to work without a heartbeat.  Is there some hook which I can pay attention to?

I don't know Angular at all, so I don't know whether this is possible.  If you have better alternative ideas, I'm all ears.  Thanks.

Comment: Check `pageshow` event as explained here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageshow_event. Not sure about browser support though.

Comment: You can subscribe to the router.events.

Comment: @sathcoder he has no access to the angular code

Comment: MutationObserver might be your friend here..

Comment: @MikeOne yeah MutationObserver would be great, but it only watches the DOM; it doesn't work on `window.location.href` for example.  @Benny I'll check out `pageshow`

Comment: You want to know when something in the view changed right? The Angular routing change might not be that relevant (being a SPA and all) - you wanted to know when a particular element appears right?

Comment: @MikeOne sure, but the element I'm looking for (`md-card`) is generic enough it could appear on any page; I need an event to fire only for a particular URL

Comment: Understood. However, you could still use MutationObserver as a 'trigger;' here. So test if you DOM object exists - and if it does, check the current URL to see if it is the one you want... Just trying to think out-of-the-box here for ya ;-)

Comment: @MikeOne thank you.  I'll give that a shot!  Hopefully later today.